# How to add login authentication and session to ReactJS React Router and Redux with MongoDB + NodeJS Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, reactjs, react-router

I have a MongoDB + NodeJS Express server, with Webpack running and able to register a user with credentials to the database. I now would like to add authentication and session when the user logs in. I'm looking into `Passport.js` but can't seem to grasp how all can be put together.

What would be the best approach to it? Any example and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

So far these are my set up.

For the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var config = require('../webpack.config.js');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var app = express();
var db;

var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/users/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Req body', req.body);
  var newUser = req.body;
  db.collection('users').insertOne(newUser, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    var newId = result.insertedId;

    db.collection('users').find({_id: newId}).next(function(err, doc) {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      res.json(doc);
    })
  })
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
});

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb', function(err, dbConnection) {
  if(err) console.log(err);

  db = dbConnection;
  var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
      var port = server.address().port;
      console.log("Started server at port", port);
  });
});
```

And as for the router (Login page being at `Login` and the register page being render at `Register`):

```
//react-router
render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component ={MainPage}
          path='/'
        >
          <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
          <Route
            component={Register} path="Register"
          />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

API POST request in redux:

```
//How registered user's credentials are stored via action in redux
  registerUser(username, email, name, password) {
    console.log('Started registering request')
    var user = {
      username: username,
      email: email,
      name: name,
      password: password,
    }

    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    }

    console.log('Adding user: ', user)

    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users`, request)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user);
      return user;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error is', err)
    })

    console.log('Ending registering request')
  },
```

Comment: use [client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions). Might be easier to understand. Plus its made by moz.

Comment: @magreenberg I'm aware of all these middlewares but I'm not understanding how any of them could be integrated with the stack that I have, especially react-router. An example would be really helpful than just a link to another middleware.

Answer (score -1):

i recommend you to use this library of JWT, it works perfectly, with expressJs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken,
after your user sign in, you give theme a JWT token like this:

```
const token = jwt.sign(
  { userId: user.userId, username: user.username },
  yourFileWItchContainTheJwtString.jwtSecret,
  { expiresIn: "1h" }//keep connected for 1 hour
);
```

if you want to verify the JWT of the user to keep them connected or to give them some authorization you can verify by using :

```
jwtPayload = <any>jwt.verify(token, yourFileWItchContainTheJwtString.jwtSecret);
//save it in locals
 res.locals.jwtPayload = jwtPayload;
```

//Get the jwt token from the head of request (do some action with the token)

```
const token = <string>req.headers["auth"];
```

you can check the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

Comment: The question is about session not JWT. There's a constant debate in using JWT for authentication regarding security.

Answer (score -2):

If i well understand you need to keep your user logged in. I would suggest to use jwt to create a token after your user is login [jwt](https://jwt.io/) and store the this token into localstorage.setItem(token).

Hope it help

Comment: Storing any kind of authorization token in the local storage would be a bad idea since localStorage doesn't have any kind of data protection whatsoever on the website. 
Tokens should be store in cookies with HttpOnly flag to make the token not accessible through Javascript and are immune to XSS and the Secure flag to guarantee the cookie is only sent over HTTPS.